# SSIS script will not load

Tags: c#, ssis-2012

I am trying to use a SSIS script to download a file.

I have created a `Http` connection name `NationwideConnection` along with a flat file connection called `allied`. Both work.  I am using the following C# script. The script fails to load. I am running on sql 2014 server 2012
Also `scriptrestults.sucess` is underlined saying it does not exist in the current context. Any suggestions.

```
// C# code
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace ST_6799d08685cb4ad78633d035fab12178.csproj
 {
 // [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "",   Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain :    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
  {
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Logging start of download
            bool fireAgain = true;
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Start  downloading " + Dts.Connections["NationwideConnection"].ConnectionString,  string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            // Get your newly added HTTP Connection Manager
            Object mySSISConnection =  Dts.Connections["NationwideConnection"].AcquireConnection(null);

            // Create a new connection
            HttpClientConnection myConnection = new HttpClientConnection(mySSISConnection);

            // Download file and use the Flat File Connectionstring (D:\SourceFiles\Products.csv)
            // to save the file (and replace the existing file)
            myConnection.DownloadFile(Dts.Connections["Allied"].ConnectionString, true);

            // Logging end of download
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Download File", "Finished downloading " + Dts.Connections["Allied"].ConnectionString, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            // Quit Script Task succesful
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging why download failed
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download File", "Download failed: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);

            // Quit Script Task unsuccesful
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: You may have accidentally deleted the ScriptResults enum when deleting other boiler plate code. Create another script task and just don't delete any of the auto generated stuff.